# Ambari throws error E090 HDFS030 Error in creation reation

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I have set up a view for file browsing in Ambari admin (Views - Add view - files), but when trying to access this view, I get the following error appearing:

> E090 HDFS030 Error in creation /user//hive/jobs/hive-job-... [HdfsApiException]

Why?

Answer (score 1):

> Solved!

The solution to my problem was that the user running "ambari-server" was not allowed to act upon behalf of the current user logged into ambari. In Hadoop terms, the ambari daemon user was not allowed to impersonate the ambari user.

To fix this, the HDFS config had to be modified to add access for my ambari-server user to impersonate everybody. For detailed howto, see this page:

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.2.0.0/bk_ambari_views_guide/content/_configuring_your_cluster_for_files_view.html